# Retrieve Buyer Address with Paypal Digital Goods Transaction (or alternate solutions)

Tags: php, paypal

I'm integrating paypal into a site for a friend, and this is the first time that I've used paypal's API.

His site operates in a high fraud market exchanging digital goods, but because he's a reseller of said goods, it's in his best interests to avoid buyer fraud (paypal chargebacks) as much as possible.

Currently I'm attempting to integrate paypal express checkout with digital goods but as part of our buyer verification, I need to specify that the user enter their address into paypal. I would like them to enter it into paypal because it's a trusted third party, and in theory, I can then get their address from paypal to verify their identity.

I can set up the website to do the standard method of having them enter their shipping address into the website and then pass the information onto paypal, but I'm afraid it would negatively impact sales.

However, with digital goods it seems that paypal doesn't handle a shipping address at all. Currently it's not a problem as he's using the premade buttons that already ask for shipping information, so I would like to replicate that functionality.

So, I have two questions:

1) Is it possible to get paypal to request a shipping address for a digital transaction?

2) Is it possible to set up an express checkout payment where the buyer enters their shipping information into paypal and NOT into my site?

I really hope somebody can help as I've been beating my head against this every night for a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paypal ipn returns the address, when you post to payapl they will request an address by default

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/

no_shipping =2 is prompt for and require an address

Comment: In addition, have a look at their AddressVerify API: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_AddressVerify

You can request access to this API call by calling their customer service team I believe. Or if they don't know anything about it, try merchant technical services (https://www.paypal.com/mts/ for suggestions who to contact.)

Comment: Sadly link is broken :(